# how to get child node by tag name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to access child nodes. so far so good. my code is

`columns = document.getElementById('columns').children[0].children;`

where i and j are loops values.

`collapseState = columns[i].children[j].children[2].style.display;`

But i am try to get the element by tag name. Lets write:

`collapseState = columns[i].children[j].children.getElementsByTagName('blahblah');`

but it gives error. How to achieve this ?

Comment: VM217:1 Uncaught TypeError: columns[i].children[j].children.getElementsByClassName is not a function(…)

Comment: `.children` is an HtmlCollection. It does not have that function. An individiual node would have that function. For instance, `.children[0].getElementsByClassName(....)`

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection

Comment: `querySelectorAll('#columns blahblah')`

Comment: What is the HTML, I am betting there is a better way.

Comment: What are you trying to do with these elements? Perhaps there's a better way to do what you're trying to accomplish without accessing each element explicitly. See [What is an XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/313880)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem stems from trying to use a function that doesn't exist on an [HtmlCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). You would need to grab an individual `ParentNode` in order to use the `getElementsByTagName` or `getElementsByClassName` functions.

`collapseState = columns[i].children[j].getElementsByTagName('blahblah');`
or

`collapseState = columns[i].children[j].children[someIndex].getElementsByTagName('blahblah');`

Comment: columns[i].children[j].children[0].getElementsByTagName("h3").innerHtml

Comment: You can't call `innerHtml` on an HtmlCollection (which is what `getElementsByTagName` returns).

`getElementsByTagName('h3')[0].innerHtml`

Answer (score 0):

may be this could help you

```
function getbytagname(parents_id, children_tag_name){
var c = document.getElementById(parents_id).children;
var x = [] ;
for(var i =0; i<c.length;i++)
 {
  if(c[i].tagName===children_tag_name){ // children_tag_name should be in capital, eg. "SPAN"
   x.push(c[i]);
  }
 };
return x;
}
```

this is just to give you an idea, you can modify this as per your requirements